# Routing DHCP through a wireless router

Tags: dhcp, routing, wifi

I have a SBS 2003 server that is running DNS/AD/DHCP. Address space is 192.168.1.1. We added a new wireless router to the network to replace a old damaged Watchguard Firewall/gateway.

Everything works well except I can not get DHCP to service from the LAN to the Wireless clients. The wireless clients can ping to the server but it's like they are not getting the DHCP server broadcast.

I have move the DHCP to the router for now and it works i.e. The workstation on both the LAN and wireless are getting address but it is causing some issues with SBS.

This wireless router is also currently acting as the gateway and firewall for the network. So the network looks like this:

Internet > Cable Modem > Wireless Router/Gateway/Firewall > Switch > Local Clients icluding SBS

How can I get the DHCP server to broadcast to both the LAN and wireless clients ?

Comment: Do you have the router configured to use a different ip and/or subnet for the lan then the wifi?

Comment: How do you have the wireless router connected to the LAN?

Comment: So what are you using for a firewall, and what specific wireless router are you using?

Answer (score 1):

By default, these wireless routers are setup to put the wireless devices on a separate address space and do NAT. You need to change that and get the wireless router to be a plain access point, not do DHCP and not do NAT.

The specifics about how to do this depend on the router model, and I almost certainly can't tell you how to do it, but I doubt it is particularly tough once you know what you are looking for.

Comment: If I turn it into a access point then it can no longer act as the gateway to a different network for example the internet in this case. 
Is that correct ? 
If that is correct then you would need to have a separate gateway configure and then add the wireless access point as another node of the network, correct ?

Comment: ?? I am confused about how the network is setup.  I was under the impression that you already have gateway to the internet.  When configured as an "access point", the device is like the wireless equivalent of a wired switch .. it connects the devices to the network.

Comment: Nope this unit is acting as both as a wireless unit and the network gateway.